# How to change value of an object array with map function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I need the entire array data by changing attribute value.But map returns only changed value.Is there any way?

input :  `[{id: 527, status: 0},{id: 528, status: 0},{id: 529, status: 0},{id: 530, status: 0}]`

required op: `[{id: 527, status: 1},{id: 528, status: 0},{id: 529, status: 0},{id: 530, status: 0}]`

```
testDetails = testDetails
    .map((values)=> values.id == '527' ? values.status = 1&&values : values)

output :[0,{id: 528, status: 0},{id: 529, status: 0},{id: 530, status: 0}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a new object with a different status for the wanted id. This approach does not mutates the original data.

```js
var data = [{ id: 527, contractor_id: 1138, role_type: "specific", passpercent_max: 100, failpercent_min: 0 }, { id: 529, contractor_id: 1138, role_type: null, passpercent_max: null, failpercent_min: null }, { id: 530, contractor_id: 1138, role_type: null, passpercent_max: null, failpercent_min: null }, { id: 531, contractor_id: 1138, role_type: null, passpercent_max: null, failpercent_min: null }],
    result = data.map(o => o.id === 527 ? { ...o, status: 1 } : o);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```